# No output observed on k8s_facts module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Team, 
I have no errors with my playbook but I see no output stored. any hint? Am getting "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!" may be due to no value in it.

```
      - name: "Get a list of all pods from any namespace"
        k8s_facts:
          kind: Pod
          kubeconfig: $WORKSPACE
          verify_ssl: no
        register: pod_list
      - debug:
          var: pod_list.stdout_lines

      - name: "Search for nodeType=gpu"
        k8s_facts:
          kubeconfig: $WORKSPACE
          kind: Node
          label_selectors:
            - nodeType=gpu
          verify_ssl: no
        register: node_list
      - debug:
          var: node_list.stdout_lines
```

Actual Output:

```
ok: [target1]

TASK [3_validations_on_ssh : debug] *****************************
ok: [target1] => {
    "pod_list.stdout_lines": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [3_validations_on_ssh : Search for nodeType=gpu] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [target1]

TASK [3_validations_on_ssh : debug] ****************************
ok: [target1] => {
    "node_list.stdout_lines": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

expected output:
List of pods and nodes that i see when i manually run kubectl and get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I don't have what is needed (i.e. a kube install...) to confirm that in seconds, I don't think the `k8s_facts` module is returning the [`stdout` common return value](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#stdout) (which is only present when the module is effectively writing to stdout, like `shell` or `command`).

You should however get the [module specific return values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_facts_module.html#return-values)

To explore that on your own simply debug the registered var directly (example for `pod_list`):

```
- debug:
    var: pod_list
```

Comment: You are right. Thanks. I got the output but its not listing one liners with just pod names and dumping whole pod yaml to screen. how can i just parse the pod names and namespaces only?